# How find an object list without a parameter in method with JpaRepository, Spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-boot, spring-data

I need to get an object list with JpaRepository but in some cases I don`t have one of the variables in method. For example:

[image: JpaRepository example]

If I need findByNombreCursoContainsIgnoreCaseAndAreaBean but I don´t have the variable **Area**, what I should do? create specifics methods for each case of my queries? Exists a method in which I can pass null value for Area and get the query for all the areas?

will be

```
findByNombreCursoContainsIgnoreCaseAndAreaBean("example", null);
```

and with this get all the list with "example" and all areas.

What I'm trying to do? A searcher in my application: I think this is not optimum:

```
public Page<Curso> searcher(String nombreCurso, Area area, int activo, Pageable pageable){      
    try {
        if(nombreCurso.isEmpty() && area!=null &&  area.getIdArea() == 0 && activo == 2) {
            return getAll(pageable);
        } if(area.getIdArea() == 0 && activo == 2) { 
            return repo.findByNombreCursoContainsIgnoreCase(nombreCurso, pageable);
        } if(activo != 2 && area.getIdArea() == 0) {    // 0 = descatalogado   / 1 = Activo
            return repo.findByNombreCursoContainsIgnoreCaseAndActivo(nombreCurso, new Integer(activo).byteValue(), pageable);
        } if(activo != 2){
            return repo.findByActivo(new Integer(activo).byteValue(), pageable);
        }else {
            return repo.findByNombreCursoContainsIgnoreCaseAndAreaBean(nombreCurso, area, pageable);
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        return getAll(pageable);
    }
                
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Way 1 . Try Optional

```
findByNombreCursoContainsIgnoreCaseAndAreaBean (..,(Optional<Area> areaOption,.){
    // some code
    if (optionalArgument.isPresent()) {
        doSomething(optionalArgument.get());
    } else {
        doSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

Way 2: While receiving data from REST

---

1. Optional Request Parameters using ie set the default value and then call respective methods

```
@GetMapping("/api/foos")
@ResponseBody
public void getFoos(@RequestParam(required = false) String id) { 
   doSomething(id);       
}
```

**OR**

2. Using Default Value 
   A Default Value for the Request Parameter

   @GetMapping("/api/foos")
   @ResponseBody
   public void getFoos(@RequestParam(defaultValue = "test") String id) {
   doSomething(id);
   }

Comment: The `Optional` class is not intended to be used as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use org.springframework.data.domain.Example. An entity model is put into example and queried by that. Since only nombre field is set as below, query criteria is build considering just that field. If you set more fields other than null, those are also added to search criteria

```
Curso curso = new Curso();
curso.setNombre(5);
Page<Curso> page = cursoRepository.findAll(Example.of(curso),pageable);
```

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-query-by-example